# How can i shorten my code and exlude a group of number?

Tags: python

First i have written the following code and i want to know if i could write it shorter?.Second i would like to exclude a group of numbers but not separately each number which is included in this group?

```
import random
L=range(1,46)
Q=range(1,21)
f1=random.sample(set(L),5)
k1=random.sample(set(Q),1)
f2=random.sample(set(L),5)
k2=random.sample(set(Q),1)
f3=random.sample(set(L),5)
k3=random.sample(set(Q),1)
f4=random.sample(set(L),5)
k4=random.sample(set(Q),1)
f5=random.sample(set(L),5)
k5=random.sample(set(Q),1)
print(f1)
print(k1)
print(f2)
print(k2)
print(f3)
print(k3)
print(f4)
print(k4)
print(f5)
print(k5)
```

Comment: why can't you use `loop` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic **[loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)**:

```
import random
L=range(1,46)
Q=range(1,21)
for i in range(5):
    f=random.sample(set(L),5)
    k=random.sample(set(Q),1)
    print(f,k,sep="\n")
```